# Prestashop: how to get the step number in the checkout header

Tags: prestashop, smarty

I'm using the theme "Classic" in Prestashop 1.7.5.0.

I'd like to get the current step of cart in the template `checkout/header.tpl` in order to get a 3 steps progress indicator such as :

1 ========> **2** ==========> 3

In the template `checkout/steps/checkout-step.tpl` I have the variable `$step_is_current` for example but I don't have this info in `header.tpl`.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it works for Prestashop `1.7.5`, but you can try something like this:

```php
<ul>
{foreach from=$steps item="step" key="index"}
            {assign var='position' value=($index + 1)}
            <li data-step="{$position}">{$position}</li>
{/foreach}
</ul>
```

I'm using Prestashop `1.7.8.5` with [classic-rocket](https://github.com/prestarocket-agence/classic-rocket) theme